# Bug in my regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm trying to look at a string and reject anything that has `seq=` or `app=` in the string. Where it gets tricky is I need elements with `q=something` or `p=something`.

The `seq=` part of the string is always preceded an `&` and `app=` is always preceded by a `?`

I have absolutely no idea where to start. I've been using http://www.rubular.com/ to try and figure it out but to no avail.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to reject the whole string if it contains seq= or app=, or parse the string and only reject key/value pairs where the key is seq or app?

Comment: @jay I removed it from the post because it was such a mess and updated the original post

Comment: @Tarwn So the URL string is a value of a hash. I'm rejecting the specific keys where the value includes app= or seq=

Comment: why are you doing it with regex when your question yesterday uses the uri parser?

Comment: @DGM I'm not entirely sure. I figured regex would be easier to define the specific subset I needed to reject while still protecting p=and q= results

Comment: nah, the parse gets you all the data in a much more usable form.  The other answer has how to get p and q out.  Do the same thing for app and seq, but reject the whole line if those keys are present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, I believe you could just reject any strings that match the following expression:

```
[\?&](?:seq|app)=
```

This will match any string that contains a `?` or `&` followed by either `app=` or `seq=`. The `?:` inside the parentheses just tells the regular expression not to bother to capture matching groups as sub-matches. They're not really necessary, but what the heck.

Here's a Rubular link with [some samples](http://www.rubular.com/r/IoKuujQt4j).

Comment: This is fantastic. Such a big help. Thank you Tarwn!